# Dynamically add React components into DIV or another react App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

CONTEXT

I'm trying to dynamically add the React component into DIV/Another React component base on event f.g onClick event.

I tried and know I can add any HTML element into DIV by JS, simply by createElement and append into the DIV. But I want to add the react component into DIV.

**Problem:**

When I append React component into DIV, It will add [object Object], I am looking for a way to be able to render and insert React Components into DIV.

Here is codeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bouman-f95mx?file=/src/App.js

```js
    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import Button from "./Button";

    const addToCanvos = () => {
      var canvos = document.querySelector(".canvos");
      canvos.append(<Button />);
    };

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Button event={addToCanvos} />
          <div className="canvos" />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-firefly-yff0x?file=/src/App.js) implementation.  Basically you need to use the useState React Hook to store all the components that you want to add as children of the canvas.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [buttonsOnCanvos, setButtonsOnCanvos] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        event={() => {
          setButtonsOnCanvos([...buttonsOnCanvos, <Button />]);
        }}
      />
      <div className="canvos">{buttonsOnCanvos}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution is awesome. Thanks, Do you think it would be work if we have different components and want to add them at the same time?

Comment: if you wanted to add multiple components the just add more items to the array

`setButtonsOnCanvos([...buttonsOnCanvos, <Component1 />,<Component2/>]);`

If you want to remove the items set the array back to empty

`setButtonsOnCanvos([])`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access the DOM directly. You can have a state to indicate whether to show the `.canvos` element or not. Then you render the `<Button />` in the div conditionally.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [showCanvos, setShowCanvos] = useState(false);

  const addToCanvos = () => {
    setShowCanvos(true)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button event={addToCanvos} />
      <div className="canvos">
        {showCanvos && <Button />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice that I moved the `addToCanvos` function into the `App` component.

Comment: This is cool what you mentioned, but this is different by my target, I have different React component, and on click on them I would like to add them into DIV dynamically, Maybe one may instance or multi-instance from the same react component.

Comment: The main target for me is to able to few React components and let the user add them into DIV and set the position on this DIV, something like drag and drop functionality. But for my first simple task, I add them by click on the component. again I start with one button

Comment: What if I want to add hundred of them through clicking?

Comment: Sorry I don't get. You want to add 100 buttons to the div when you click once?

Comment: Yes, I want if user click on add button, able to add React component to the DIV DOM

Comment: ```const add = () => {

  const Div=document.createElement("div");
  const BTN=document.createElement("button");
  BTN.innerHTML="Hello World!";
  Div.append(BTN);

  document
    .querySelector(".div2")
    .append(<ButtonM/>);
};```

Comment: But instead of the above code, I would like to add React component into the sub-dom of DIV